# How do you prove that a "group presentation" actually specifies a group?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we are given a group presentation. Let's jump in the deep end with:

$$\operatorname {Dic}_n = \langle {a, b: a^{2 n} = e, b^2 = a^n, b^{-1} a b = a^{-1} }\rangle$$

(the dicyclic group of order $4 n$).

It is straightforward but tedious to demonstrate (eventually) that all elements of $\operatorname {Dic}_n$ are of the form $a^k b^j$, where $0 \le k < 2 n$ and $j \in \{0, 1\}$ (at least, it looks plausible from what I see on Wikipedia, I haven't worked through it rigorously yet). Thus it can then be shown that $\operatorname {Dic}_n$ is closed.

But to do this, it is necessary to make the assumptions (a) that the group operation is associative, and b) that $e$ is an identity element, and so, together with the assumed associativity of the group operation, that it is *the* identity.

But is it possible to prove by first principles that an algebraic structure which is defined by a particular presentation is *necessarily* associative?

And having done so, how can we subsequently demonstrate from a given presentation (that we are assured is a "group presentation") that this element that we have defined as $e$, is *actually* an identity element?

Once one has established these above issues, it is then easy to show that every element has a unique inverse by successive group operations to "undo" an arbitrary element (in its form $a^k b^j$ from above, for example).

Summary: how does one prove the associativity and existence of the identity from a given arbitrary group presentation?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a group presentation? Have you studied free groups?

Comment: After defining a group presentation to be the quotient of a free group, associativity and the existence of the identity is obvious.

Comment: @a1402 Yes I *have* been introduced to the concept of a "free group", but not formally. The only texts I have studied have not integrated the concepts of "free group" and "group presentation" as such, and I have not seen a formal definition of a "group presentation" beyond the intuitive idea that it's got a set of generators, and a set of equations defining relations on those generators which equate certain words to some distinguished element "$e$". Never seen the bits all linked together. Hence this question. Hoping for help.

Comment: Let $F(x,y)$ be a free group with free generators $x$ and $y$,
$H$ be a normal subgroup generated by the given relations,
i.e. $H$ is the normal closure of the subgroup $\langle x^{2n},x^ny^{-2},y^{-1}xyx\rangle$ in $F$.
Then our group $Dic_n$ is the factor group $F(x,y)/H$.

Answer (score 5):

A group presentation $\langle X\mid R\rangle$ is defined to be $F/\langle R^F\rangle$, where $F$ is the [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) on the set $X$ (i.e. reduced words in $X\cup X^{-1}$) and the [normal closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_closure_(group_theory)) $\langle R^F\rangle$ is the intersection of all normal subgroups of $F$ containing $R$, equivalently the smallest normal subgroup of $F$ containing $R$. Elements of $R$ are relators, that is words $w$ with $w=e$. In your example, where you have $x=y$ as a relation, the corresponding relator is $y^{-1}x\in R$.

The existence of an identity and associativity are therefore inherited from $F$.

Comment: Given what you say, it is correct to say that you cannot then assume, for a given group presentation in a particular form (say, as the one I gave above) that the group is closed and has inverses? That is, it is still necessary for this to be proved for a given presentation? But that a given "free group" is *defined* with an associative operation? Where in the definition of the free group is it given that the operator is associative? And where is it established that such a free group actually *has* an identity? In other words, what are our axioms here?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to prove this for a given presentation since one can show that a quotient group is indeed a group. It is necessary to prove free groups exist - these are often defined by their universal property. You can prove by induction on the length of a word that concatenation is associative - there are a few existing questions about this on MSE. For any nonempty set $X$, there is some $x\in X$ and $x^{-1}\in X^{-1}$ so $xx^{-1}$ reduces to the empty word, which is the identity, so every free group on a non-empty set has an identity.

Comment: You might like to check out a book on presentations of groups. I recommend the book by D. Johnson.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go explore. I think I have some way to go.